# Node.js module call a root function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can a NodeJS module call a root function?

```
function test(){
   console.log("test function called");
}

var module = require("module");
module.INT();
```

Module

```
exports.INT = function() {
    test();
};
```

Reason why I am writing a node npm module that uses `createReadStream(` `readStream.on('end'` loading in the bytes of a local file (but does not return or wait to return on the readStream 'end' handler). Due to the asynchronous nature of Node.js? when requiring in and calling the module.

Comment: It doesnt work this way. you can write a callback for it.or a promise

Comment: No, you ​can’t.

Comment: Thanks @JF, I tried writing a callback but there is no createReadStream( on('end' callback functionality? @ abdul-rehman-sayed.

Comment: `there is no createReadStream( on('end' callback functionality?`  The docs say's , -> `on error or end the file descriptor will be closed automatically.`  So reading this, it would seem there is an `end` event callback..

Comment: @Keith let me rephrase that there is a callback on('end' function for createReadStream( but if you create a module with a createReadStream(. it won't return the on('end' function due to it being asynchronous (as the on('end' handler completes after the return is fired due to it being non-blocking) and the data is still been streamed.